# What kind of statistical analysis can I use to compare distance estimates in three experimental methods?

Tags: testing, statistics, statistical-test

I have three data sets of distance estimates by humans in three different experimental methods such as (real life, virtual reality, and computer-based simulation). I want to compare how do humans differ in estimating distances in these three experimental methods. Which statistical analysis would be good to use for it? My dependent variable is the distance estimates and independent variable are the three different experimental conditions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether an individual took part in all 3 conditions, or if you essentially have 3 different experiments with an entirely new subject pool each time

In the first case, where a single individual took part in all conditions, you could use a One-way repeated measures ANOVA, with `method` as a 3 level within-subjects factor. Alternatively, a mixed-effects regression with random slopes/intercepts for the subjects

In the second case, where an individual only took part in 1 condition, you could simply use a One-way ANOVA, with `method` as a 3 level between-subjects factor

Comment: Hi Simon, Thank you for the response. Can you brief me a bit about how I can use the mixed effects regression model in this case? I am trying to compare distance estimates by participants in three different experimental methods. So here my independent variable is the experimental method and dependent variables are the distance estimates.